# Android ResourceNotFoundException in preview custom View

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got a custom view, let's call it `CustomView`. In the initialization, I call the following method

```
textPaint.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(),R.font.pretty_font));
```

In the app, this view works perfectly and the font is displayed as it should but the problem is that the preview of the view wont load in the editor with the following details:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f090000 could not be retrieved.
>
> at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:365)
>     at
>   androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:230)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.myapp.view.views.CustomView.init(CustomView.java:490)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.myapp.view.views.CustomView.initAttrs(CustomView.java:484)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.myapp.view.views.CustomView.(CustomView.java:116)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:186)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:144)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:418)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:429)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:333)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:323)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:200)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:572)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:698)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Why won't this resource be loaded in the editor but it has no problem running in the app?
FYI, MinSdk = 21 and TargetSdk = 28

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't call `setTypeface` in design mode. Use:

```
if (!isInEditMode()) {
textPaint.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(),R.font.pretty_font))
}
```

Comment: So is programmatically setting a font in a custom view not supported in Android Studio preview?

Comment: That's not really an answer. How to avoid this crash when in Edit mode?

Comment: You can look here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36942641 but actually you don't need to care about fonts in design mode, that's not important.